# Reading/Writing to and from a shared Cache based on Enterprise Library

Tags: c#, caching, enterprise-library

I'm using Enterprise Lib 5.0 caching app block and I'm trying to figure out the best way to handle read/writes in a multi threaded scenario. 
Is taking a lock on  write and not taking a lock on read the recommended approach?

```
Update(string key, object value)
{
     lock(syncLock)
     { 
        cacheManager.Add(key,value);
     }
}
object Read(string key)
{
     object o = cacheManager.GetData(key);
     return o;
 }
  //OR is the following Read recommended using a lock
object Read(string key)
{   
     lock(syncLock)
     {
       object o = cacheManager.GetData(key);
       return o;
     }
}
```

My concern is that if one thread is about to update the item for a specific key at the same time as another thread is about to read the item for the same key.Can this cause races?

Would it make sense to have a dictionary of "keys" to "ReaderWriterLockSlim"s so that you would essentially take a lock for only a specifc key as opposed to a "common" lock in a multi threaded scenario like a web app:

Basically something like this:

```
Dictionary<string,ReaderWriterLockSlim> dict = new Dictionary<string,ReaderWriterLockSlim> ();

void Update(string key, object value)
{
     dict[key].EnterWriteLock();
     cacheManager.Add(key,value);
     dict[key].ExitWriteLock();         
}

object Read(string key)
{
     dict[key].EnterReadLock();    
     object o = cacheManager.GetData(key);
     dict[key].ExitReadLock();    
     return o;
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't have to do your own locking with [The Caching Application Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664753%28v=PandP.50%29.aspx) because "you are assured that the block performs in a thread-safe manner".

If you take a look at the source code for `Cache` you will see that the `Add`, `Remove`, and `GetData` methods all obtain locks on the in-memory cache before performing any operations.

Comment: Wouldn't you still want a lock around the logic where you are initially adding items to the cache?  IE: if GetData == Null { Add } ... but what if another thread called Add between your null check and your Add ala some form of [double checking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking)

Comment: @felickz: yes -- that's a good distinction -- if you are calling multiple methods (such as Contains and then Add) and wish them to be atomic then you would have to synchronize access.